# kineticjs and iOS Resource Limits

Tags: javascript, ios, resources, kineticjs

I was wondering if anyone ran into this problem, and when it occurs? I'm working on a project with a round 90mb om images on different layers. I am wondering how this gonna react on iOS, and what i am already can to to prevent this.

Comment: could you please be specific of the problem you are facing? is it about loading of 90mb images, or performance or ??

Comment: I'm facing a lot of crash issues on Retina iPad with latest KineticJS 4.4.2. I found this question and was wondering if everything went ok? There are some reports about slow performance due to higher pixelRatio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753373/improving-slow-canvas-animation-on-retina-ipad-kineticjs

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was looking for limits such as which are specified in de developer article from iOS. 5Mb image limt etc etc, and if somebody did ran into those issues. My provlem is stretching far from iOS only, but it's all mobile devices. Mobile devices lack memory. I'm trying to find a way to delete images and draw them only when needed...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem, apart from the obvious load times. If tbe 90MB consists of 1000 small images you want to animate at the same time, then yes, you will have a problem.

I found performance on iPad & iPhone pretty good, compared to other mobile devices.

Comment: Well, i got around 90mb of images indeed. The application is (not retina) 940 x 440. All images are initalized and placed on the canvas (on different layers), and are therefor loaded in the DOM, which could exceeding the max of mb's a mobile site can have...